# ESP8266 NODEMCU V3, HOW TO USE AND CONTROL V3 OUTPUT POWER

Tags: esp8266, motor

this is my very first post in here so I apologise if I am not giving you all the information that I should.

I am creating this topic to ask you help regarding how to control and use the v3 output of my Nodemcu.

I have a script which is working fine to power on and off a led by using one of the GPIO and the ground. However, my project requires to power on a small motor for about 2 seconds and then stop it. If I connect this motor to one of the GPIO and the ground I can control it but it runs very slow. If I connect the motor to the 3V output it goes fine but I can't turn it on or off. The motor requires 3V to run properly. How can I turn it on and off by powering it from that 3V output?

What am I missing?

I have a 4n25 chip which I saw in a video that has been used for a similar project however the vide is in Portuguese and I am not able to follow it properly.

Can please someone advice?

Thank you for your time,

Ade

Comment: I would suggest to control the motor using FET rather than directly attaching it ESP pin. As these pins cannot supply enough current and you can damage your ESP by doing this. So use FET for motor and control the FET using gpio's of ESP, that will turn ON and OFF the motor.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for replying so fast.
Which one would you suggest?

IRFZ44 Power MOSFET TO-220
or
20pcs/lot 2n7000 To92 Small Signal Mosfet 200 Mamps, 60 Volts N-channel To-92

Comment: irLz44n is the the logic-level version of the ever-popular irF44n, and one i use with ESPs a lot. be careful ordering them from a cut-rate webfront or auction house though; i've gotten ones that clearly were out of spec from places like that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control the "V3" output. It's a 3.3V power supply output. Think of it like a battery. It's always on and always giving power.

Instead, you need to add a "switch" to control that power that the ESP8266 can itself control, such as a MOSFET or a motor driver (H-Bridge).